# xfce power-manager->monitor difference between sleep/switch off

Tags: power-management, arch-linux, xfce, power-options

If I go to Settings-PowerManager->Monitor tab there are (among others) two sliders for management. 
1. "Put Display to sleep when computer is inactive for:"
2. "Switch off display when computer is inactive for:"

Whats the difference between putting monitor to sleep/switch it off? I cannot figure it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Put the display to sleep" and "Switch off the display" are different DPMS modes.

There are four DPMS modes:

- **Normal**: what your monitor is doing when you're using it
- **Standby**: a power saving mode, the screen is blanked by turning the RGB guns off
- **Suspend**: another power saving mode, similar to standby, but the power supply to the monitor is also turned off, saving even more power
- **Off**: the monitor is actually turned off, except for a circuit that listens for a signal to turn it back on; it uses almost no power, but it takes longer to turn back on than the other power saving modes

There are more technical details, including the watts used in each mode, [here](http://webpages.charter.net/dperr/dpms.htm).

Xfce's "Put the display to sleep" is either DPMS **standby** or **suspend**, I'm not sure which. "Switch off the display" uses DPMS **off** mode.

Now, these DPMS modes clearly only have meaning for CRT monitors. LCD monitors interpret DPMS signals differently. It might depend on the monitor, but **there is probably no difference for LCD monitors**. They just turn off if they receive any of the DPMS power saving signals.

Which setting should you use, then? Again, it probably doesn't matter. I would use "Switch off the display", since that's actually what I want my monitor to do. Telling your monitor to go into a CRT power saving mode when you know it's just going to turn off anyway seems a bit backwards to me.

Answer (score 1):

Put display to sleep = put into lower power consumption mode

Switching off display = simply turn screen to black

Comment: In my experience the "sleep" mode is just switching the monitor off as well. (At least it looks like)